# how can I remove tool from panel in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I would like to remove the tool from my panel;
SO I have this code, when I add tool Ext.widget to my panel and then I would like to remove this just created tool, how can I do this. I haven't fount the removeTool method. and I tried to us remove method and remove it, but nothing; Here is the code:

```
if (...) {
    var a = Ext.widget({
        id: 'kuku',
        xtype: 'tool',
        type: 'close',
        handler: Ext.Function.bind(me.close, me, [])
    });

    if (closable && !me.hasUICls('closable')) {
        me.addClsWithUI('closable');
        me.addTool(a);
    }
} else {
    if (Ext.getCmp('kuku') != null) {
        me.remove("kuku", false); //here how can I remove??
        me.doLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unable to remove using id, try using component ref. as arg... something like below

```
me.remove(Ext.getCmp('kuku'), false);
```